# Process.getInputStream() encoding issue

Tags: java, encoding, process

I have the following lines of code.I want to use proper encoding scheme.

```
Process process = processBuilder.start();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
```

My eclipse is by default using `Windows-1252` encoding.While when I run chcp command on command prompt The result is `codepage 437`.

This means the stream of bytes that I get from command line is encoded by using (**codepage437**)different scheme than the one used by JVM(**windows1252**).How do I synchronise between the two when I want my application to run across different platforms.[I can not hardcode to use code 437 in my java application]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has nothing to do with it. At runtime, your constants are UTF-16 strings, independent of whatever encoding for Java source you have set in Eclipse. Your program that reads from the stream simply has to know the encoding in use in the process you launch. That will, as you note, depend on what sort of computer you are running on, what your settings are, and choices  made by the creator of the program you launch. I'd expect that the literal values of the bytes written by a native non-_UNICODE program on Windows to appear on the stream. If the program you are running was built as an _UNICODE application, it's an interesting question what would appear on the stream ... UTF-16? In any case, any programmer creating any command-line program can send whatever they like down the standard output stream: even if every other program on the system is coughing up, say, Windows-1252, one particular program might write UTF-8 and be documented to do so for use with `>` redirection into a file. You just have to know.

Comment: chcp just tells which coding scheme is being used in command prompt

Comment: How do I check the encoding in use in the process that I have launched?

Comment: You cannot. At the lowest level, program write bytes into file references, and those bytes turn up on the other end of the pipe. Nothing knows what, if any, encoding is in use. You can try auto-detecting the encoding; java has a bit of a guesser, others can be found in libraries.